# Presto UI + convert presto UI details to logs or database

Tags: linux, presto

We have medium presto cluster with 12 presto workers ,

all presto workers are installed on Linux machines

Presto have web interface running on port 8080 of the coordinator node:

[image]

How we can store the presto UI running details in files or may be some other database ?

I will give here short example ,

in the field **running queries** , we can see the queries that runs in parallels

[image]

sometimes we start with few queries and some times we reached `20-30` queries in parallels

**running queries** details are displayed in presto UI , but we cant put our eyes always on presto UI to understand how many quarries are running each few second/s

so we are wondering , if we can logging all **running queries** numbers to some log/s or some database

the goal is to look on that logs ( in our free time ) and verify the number of running quarries along of week / or month and gives statistics

of course running queries is one thing that we want to save on log/s or database , but this is only example and we want to saved to logs or database other details as queries details or how many queries get **INTERNAL ERRROR** or how many queries was failed and so on ...